# Best data-structure/db/binary-format for holding hierarchic elements

Tags: sql, c, database, design-patterns, data-structures

I have the following hierarchic entities:

```
Country, City, Street.
Every country has cities, every city has streets.
```

I wrote pseudo-code for what I want to run:

```
handle_country_before(country)
for city in country:
    handle_city_before(city)
    for street in city:
        handle_street_before(street)
        handle_street_after(street)
    handle_city_after(city)
handle_country_after(country)
```

### I tried the following approaches:

**The `document`(noSql) approach:**

I saved all my data in a flat manner:

```
{
    country : { 
        # Country "x1" info corresponding with the street
    },
    city : {
        # City "y1" info corresponding with the street
    },
    street : {
        # street info...
    }
}

{
    country : { 
        # Country "x1" info corresponding with the street
    },
    city : {
        # City "y1" info corresponding with the street
    },
    street : {
        # street info...
    }
}

{
    country : { 
        # Country "x1" info corresponding with the street
    },
    city : {
        # City "y1" info corresponding with the street
    },
    street : {
        # street info...
    }
}

{
    country : { 
        # Country "x1" info corresponding with the street
    },
    city : {
        # City "y2" info corresponding with the street
    },
    street : {
        # street info...
    }
}

{
    country : { 
        # Country "x1" info corresponding with the street
    },
    city : {
        # City "y2" info corresponding with the street
    },
    street : {
        # street info...
    }
}
```

Using this method, I had to use the following pseudo-code:

```
    last_country = 0
    last_city = 0
    last_street = 0
    for element in elements:
        if element.country.id != last_country_id:
            if (0 != last_country) :
                handle_country_after(last_country)
            handle_country_before(element.country)
        if element.city.id != city:
            if (0 != last_city) :
                handle_country_after(last_city)
            handle_country_before(element.city)     
        if element.street.id != street:
            if (0 != last_street) :
                handle_country_after(last_street)
            handle_country_before(element.street)
```

The disadvantage: I feel like this approach is a little bit over-kill and the use of the flat structure is not fit for my case, furthermore it was very very slow and space inefficient.

**The SQL approach:**

I saved each entity in a table: Country, City, Street and iterated it with the following code:

```
    country_cursor = query('select * from countries')
    for country in country_cursor:
        handle_country_before(country)
        city_cursor = query('select * from cities where parent_country_ref=%s' % (country.id))
        for city in city_cursor:
            street_cursor = query('select * from streets where parent_city_ref=%s' % (city.id))
            ...
            ...
        ...
        handle_country_after(country)
```

at the beginning, it looked like the best approach. But as I added more metadata tables and had to use JOIN statements it became increasingly slower, then I tried using a materialized view to speeding up things a little but got the got the same result as using documents.

**The custom format approach:**

I tried saving the information in my own binary-serialization format:

`<number of countries>[1st-country-data]<number of cities>[1nd-city-data]<number of streets>[1st-street-data][2nd-street-data][3rd-street...]...`

the disadvantage: this couldn't scale, I couldn't update information, I couldn't fetch a particular city/street, every search was O(n).

**What I am looking for** is a serialization format/DB which will be:

1. Able to add/update fields for existing elements
2. Efficient in speed, space and memory
3. C compliant (no CPP)

Comment: `But as I added more metadata tables and had to use JOIN statements it became increasingly slower` why did you add more metadata? why do you need joins? have you used indexes?

Comment: @Lashane, let's say every city has a mayor, and I also want to get the current mayor of the city as I iterate it. I have to do cartesian product of the cities and the mayors and select the mayor that match the city.

Comment: how many mayors city can have? how many cities could be under single mayor?

Comment: @Lashane, the table of mayors holds all the previous mayors of the city as well but only the current mayor record has reference to the city which is not null

Comment: it does not answer my question

Comment: @Lashane, one city under each mayor, one **active** mayor per city

Comment: right, which effectively means 1 to 1 relationship, how do we store such data?

Comment: Your requirements are not sufficient. Is the data small enough to comfortably fit in memory? Do you envision wanting to query a single city, or mayor, or country? Does the speed of update matter? Will there be multiple threads or processes accessing the data? The design of your persistence mechanism will depend on all of that, and more. You haven't given enough information for us to make any kind of recommendation.

Comment: Having to do a Cartesian product of the cities and mayors in order to get the mayor to match the city is a problem with the database design, not the fundamental idea of a relational data model. Create an index. Or, possibly better, a relationship table that holds the city id and the id of the current mayor. There are well-known methods for efficiently doing the kind of things you're doing, with a relational database. Don't try to re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

the fastest approach in your case is to use de-normalized data, create flat file/table with following information:

```
country    city    street    current mayor    additional information
```

of course data should be sorted, of course you will not use heavy to parse formats like json/xml, only pure text

then you will be able to use single loop to iterate over this array

to speed up iteration a little bit you can try to split single file into multiple ones with fixed-width rows

Comment: This approach is identical to the `document`/`materialized view` approach

Comment: @Aviv yes, its almost identical, it is the fastest approach

Comment: This is only "the fastest" if all you want to do is load all of the data. And it has scaling problems once the amount of data involved exceeds the memory available on your machine. Plus, any update will require rewriting the entire file. Without knowing what all the OP wants to do with the data, I'd be hesitant to suggest this, or any, approach.

Comment: @JimMischel OP provided pseudo code of what he want to achieve

Comment: He also provided, at the bottom of the question, a **What I am looking for** list, the first two of which are not achieved by your proposed solution.

Comment: @JimMischel why? you can add/update text file while keeping it sorted, you can add/update data in db table, this is the most efficient in speed, not in memory, but it is always tradeoff, you cannot have both in such use case, and of course OP can implement it in pure C

Comment: Updating a single record in a text file requires rewriting the entire file. That doesn't seem to be particularly fast if the file is very large. Also, if the mayor's name changes or a street name changes, you have to apply that change to every affected record. You can do it with this representation, but it's going to be cumbersome. There are many ways to solve the OP's problem. This just happens to be, in my opinion, one of the worst possible ways.

Comment: @JimMischel I'm not saying that it is fastest approach for modification, only for iteration. There is no requirement in op post. If you have variant which is fastest for both use cases - you can share it.

Comment: But there *Is* a requirement in the OP's post for updating. The first of his **What I am looking for** items is, "Able to add/update fields for existing elements." And I do have an alternative: use the database. That's what I recommended in comments. It's not "fastest" for anything, but it's a very good option that does everything the OP wants reasonably quickly.

Comment: @JimMischel there is no requirement for fast updates, I've suggested database too